# Angular mat-table with possibility to add editable rows

Tags: angular, forms, ngrx

I would like to build table with editable cells ( each cell is an input) and possibility to add new row below filled row.On init saved date will be taken from BE. I would like to use angular material table (mat-table) .
More or less it should work like this: [LINK TO EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/github/vaibhavphutane/inline-editable-table-angular9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser-table%2Fuser-table.component.ts)

In most cases in my app I am using NGRX and EntityAdapter. Is there any good approach how to achieve behaviour mentioned above with NGRX/EntityAdapter? Is NGRX useful in that particular case ?

I started to implement forms with https://github.com/MrWolfZ/ngrx-forms  and dynamic array : https://ngrx-forms-example-app-v2.herokuapp.com/dynamic . But I am not sure if it will be easy to use array and iterate it in reducer.

Could you please give me advice in my case?